# Why Async.Sequential doesn't work as expected (but works in FSI)?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, f#-interactive

```
open System
open System.Net

let fetchUrlAsync url = 
    async {
        Console.WriteLine(sprintf "Fetch <%s>" url)
        let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
        use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()   
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
        use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream) 
        let html = reader.ReadToEnd() 
        Console.WriteLine(sprintf "finished downloading %s. Length = %i" url html.Length)
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    ["http://bing.com"; "http://ya.ru"; "http://google.com"]
    |> List.map fetchUrlAsync
    |> Async.Sequential
    |> Async.Ignore
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The output:

```
Fetch <http://bing.com>
Fetch <http://ya.ru>
Fetch <http://google.com>
finished downloading http://google.com. Length = 50592
finished downloading http://ya.ru. Length = 20541
finished downloading http://bing.com. Length = 81386
```

I don't expect such an output (but perhaps I'm wrong with my expectations). But if I run the same code in F# interactive the output is (as I expected):

```
Fetch <http://bing.com>
finished downloading http://bing.com. Length = 81386
Fetch <http://ya.ru>
finished downloading http://ya.ru. Length = 20544
Fetch <http://google.com>
finished downloading http://google.com. Length = 50561
```

Why the code behaves differently when running from Rider (console application) and from F# Interactive? If the first output is correct, then what is the difference between Async.Sequential and Async.Parallel? If the first output is incorrect, then how to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, `Async.Sequential` is just implemented as:

```
static member Sequential computations = 
    Async.Parallel(computations, maxDegreeOfParallelism=1)
```

Though [the RFC allows this](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp.Core-4.7.0/FS-1067-Async-Sequential.md#detailed-design-maxdegreeofparallelism), this is expected to, well, run sequentially.
It's been [discovered to be a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7737). And it has been [fixed by #7596](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/7596).

The fix has now only shipped on VS. But it's not in  mainline `FSharp.Core` nuget feed yet.

> The only way to get the fix currently is through VS2019 16.4 FSI.

That's why you're seeing that it works correctly in FSI, but not in your compiled application.

**Solution**

Watch #7956, and wait for it to ship.

Comment: The package FSharp.Core 4.7.1 is available on NuGet.
The problem seems to be fixed.